# FFMPEG hold multiple frames and use as a movie

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that I'm trying to create jump shots from. For example I want the output of my command to show frame 5 of the original clip for 30 frames, and frame 25 of the OG clip to show for 30 frames.

assuming the OG clip is 30 FPS

```
ffmpeg -t 1 -i og_clip.mp4 -filter_complex "
    [0]select=eq(n\,5)[H1];[0][H1]overlay[O1];
    [0]select=eq(n\,25)[H2];[0][H2]overlay[O2];
    [O1][O2]concat=n=2[Merge]" -map "[Merge]" out.mp4
```

The above doesnt work right.

What I've been doing up until now has been a two part command:

```
ffmpeg -i og_clip.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,5)" -vframes 1 -y out_0.png
ffmpeg -i og_clip.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n\,25)" -vframes 1 -y out_1.png
ffmpeg -t 1 -i og_clip.mp4 -i out_0.png -i out_1.png -filter_complex "
    [0][1]overlay[H1];[0][2]overlay[H2];
    [H1][H2]concat=n=2[Merge]" -map "[Merge]" out.mp4
```

Which has been working for me. The only problem is that the process of converting to a png first for each frame I want to use, takes too long. I'm trying to condense it all into one command. I figure that the encoding of the png is what takes so long.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -t 1 -i og_clip.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]select=eq(n\,5)+eq(n\,25),settb=1/30,setpts=N*30,fps=30" -an out.mp4`

After selecting the frames, the timestamps are adjusted to be 30 frames apart. Then the fps filter will plug those gaps with cloned frames.

Comment: Thanks! This works so I'll mark it as accepted answer. I was wondering if you could give me more info on what "-an" is? also the "settb=1/30"?

Comment: `-an` dsables audio in case your source has it. `settb=1/30` sets timebase to `1/.30` so that a timestamp difference of 30 represents 1 second..

Comment: Thanks. Ok so I found it didnt totally work. I wanted to expand upon this, and i noticed that it wouldnt work if I did eq(n\,150)+eq(n\,250).

This is because the -t 1 line will only look at the first 1 second of the clip, and frame 150, and 250 are outside of that. instead I made the line:

ffmpeg -i og_clip.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]select=eq(n\,150)+eq(n\,250),settb=1/30,setpts=N*30,fps=30[clips];[clips]trim=duration=2" -an -y out.mp4

does that look fine to you?

Comment: Yes, if you limit input demuxing, then you'll never supply those frames to the select filter. So, you have to know or guess the timestamp of the last frame you want. If you leave -t out then ffmpeg will process the entire file, which is inefficient if your last frame isn't near the end of the file.